# How to get a-channel from LAB (l*a*b) color space in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am new to opencv and trying to convert RGB images to LAB color space. I am doing that using below code.

```
data_path = 'D:/Images/'
image_name= '1.png'
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(data_path, image_name),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) # Reads image from disk 
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB) # changes RGB to LAB color space

img = img [127.5, 1, 127.5]  # This i was trying to get a-channel only but gives error
```

Now I just want to use only a-channel of the LAB Image to feed to my program as 1 channel input. How can I use only a-channel of the LAB color space image?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pipe the L channel to a separate program - potentially in a different language?

Comment: @ Mark Setchell I wanted to separate every channel and wanted to use only a-channel output. I have done that using split function. Thanks
    l_channel, a_channel, b_channel = cv2.split(img)

Comment: Why do people want to downvote everything? It was a genuine question.

Comment: Beats me too. I almost never downvote unless something is awfully incorrect and potentially damaging or dangerous. Good answers will naturally float to the top through upvoting anyway without nasty, vindictive downvoting. But it takes all sorts to make a world...

Answer (score 6):

I am using opencv2 and python to solve this problem

```
    import cv2
    input = cv2.imread('path_to_image.png')
    cv2.imshow('Hello World', input)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    lab = cv2.cvtColor(input,cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    cv2.imshow("l*a*b",lab)

    L,A,B=cv2.split(lab)
    cv2.imshow("L_Channel",L) # For L Channel
    cv2.imshow("A_Channel",A) # For A Channel (Here's what You need)
    cv2.imshow("B_Channel",B) # For B Channel

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hope this helps you to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issue with below line of code

```
l_channel, a_channel, b_channel = cv2.split(img) #splits the image into 3 channles l, a and b
```

it separates the image into l, a and b channels which I wanted. It was easy but as I am new to opencv I did not know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to plot Lab channels in python. You can find more details in [this article](https://fairyonice.github.io/Color-space-defenitions-in-python-RGB-and-LAB.html) that I've used as a reference.

```py
    from keras.preprocessing.image import  img_to_array, load_img
    from skimage.color import rgb2lab, lab2rgb
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    
    def extract_single_dim_from_LAB_convert_to_RGB(image,idim):
        '''
        image is a single lab image of shape (None,None,3)
        '''
        z = np.zeros(image.shape)
        if idim != 0 :
            z[:,:,0]=80 ## I need brightness to plot the image along 1st or 2nd axis
        z[:,:,idim] = image[:,:,idim]
        z = lab2rgb(z)
        return(z)
    
    def plot_lab_spectrums():
        # Get image
        img = img_to_array(load_img("<image_path>",target_size=(400,400)))
        lab = rgb2lab(img/255.0)
        lab_l = extract_single_dim_from_LAB_convert_to_RGB(lab,0)
        lab_a = extract_single_dim_from_LAB_convert_to_RGB(lab,1)
        lab_db = extract_single_dim_from_LAB_convert_to_RGB(lab,2)
    
        # Plot the results
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(12, 4))
        data = [('L: lightness', lab_l), ('a: green-magenta channel', lab_a), ('b: blue-yellow channel', lab_db)]
    
        for ax, (title, img) in zip(axes, data):
            ax.set_title(title)
            ax.imshow(img)
            ax.axis('off')
    
        fig.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
    
    plot_lab_spectrums()
```

[image]